# Pushing an Object to Array in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to push an `Object` to an `Array` using the following command:

`a = a.concat(b);`

```
a = [];
b = {a: Object1, b: Object2 ....};
```

So I wan to have array a to be like `a = [Object1, Object2...]`

But the above statement results in:

```
a = [[Object1, Object2...][Object11, Object12...]];
```

How can I achieve this in JS?

Comment: `a.push(b);`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I´m understanding what you want, you want just objects, not the keys. So, could be:

```
for( var key in b ){
   var value = b[key];
   a.push(value);
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

> The **`Object.values()`** method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property values,

You could use the Object `values` method  **[`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)**, like :

```
Object.values(b);
```

**Example :**

```js
var a = [];
var obj_1 = {'attr_1': 'val_1', 'attr_2': 'val_2'};
var obj_2 = {'attr_3': 'val_3', 'attr_4': 'val_4'};

var b = {'a': obj_1, 'b': obj_2};

a = Object.values(b);

console.log( a );
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Check my update, I got you, `Object.values()` is what you're searching for.

Comment: Is it really more beneficial in this case to create a third object to call `Object.values()` on rather than just: `a.push(obj_1); a.push(obj_2);`?...

Comment: Same result. The value of b is like: `b = {a:ObjectA, c: ObjectC, ...}`

Comment: What you mean by `ObjectA` and `ObjectC` ? give us a real case so we can understand more what you want to achieve

Comment: @user1012181 the `Object.values(b)` does the same thing that @Andre suggest in the accepted answer !!

Answer (score 0):

You are concatenating two arrays with `Array.concat()` you need to use `Array.push()`.

```
var a = [ObjectA];
var b = ObjectB;
a.push(b);

// a = [ObjectA, ObjectB];
```

Comment: var b = {ObjectA, ObjectB}

Comment: That makes no sense in JS unless those objects are _property values_ of `b`: `var b = {a: ObjectA, b: ObjectB}`

Comment: yeah the value is like this `b = {a:ObjectA, c: ObjectC, ...}`

Comment: If `a` is an Array then try `a.concat(Object.values(b))`. This will concatenate the values from `b` to the `a` array.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let a = [];
let b = {a:1, b:2, c:3};

for(obj in b){
  let val = {};
  val[obj] = b[obj];
  a.push(val);
}

console.log(a);
```

Did you mean something like this ?